# Add list of items to another object as a list where two values are equal

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have 2 objects as below:

```
public class object1
{
    public int Object1ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public List<object2> ListOfObject2 { get; set; }
}

public class object2
{
    public int Object2ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue2 { get; set; }
    public int Object1LinkedID { get; set; }
}
```

Object1ID and Object2ID are unique ids.

I populate both of them as lists (so I have a list of Object1s and a list of Object2s).

```
List<Object1> listObject1 = new List<Object1>();
List<Object2> listObject2 = new List<Object2>();
```

I'd like to add all of the Object2s to Object1 where `Object1LinkedID` is equal to `Object1`. This can be into a new Object or just an update to original Object1 list.

Comment: Where Object1LinkedID is equal to what? to the Object1ID of a particular instance of object1? I don't understand your `where Object1LinkedID is equal to Object1` condition.

Comment: object2.Object1LinkedID = ojbect1.Object1ID. In SQL I would join on that ID SELECT * FROM Object1 JOIN Object2 ON Object1.Object1ID = Ojbect2.Object1LinkedID or something along those lines

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var groups = listObject2.GroupBy(o2 => o2.Object1LinkedID);
foreach(var o1Group in groups)
{
    object1 o1 = listObject1.Where(o => o.Object1ID == o1Group.Key).First();
    o1.ListOfObject2.AddRange(o1Group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from o1 in listObject1
        join o2 in listObject2
            on o1.Object1ID equals o2.Object1LinkedID
            into go2
        select new {O1 = o1, O2Coll = go2};

foreach (var rel in query)
{
    rel.O1.ListOfObject2.AddRange(rel.O2Coll);
}
```

or

```
foreach (var object1 in listObject1)
{
    int o1Id = object1.Object1ID;
    object1.ListOfObject2.AddRange(listObject2.Where(o => o.Object1LinkedID == o1Id));
}
```